# How to make xmlroot a specific attribute in C#

Tags: c#, deserialization

I recently have change my program to deserialize XML files. I created a class but it needs to be under certain attribute. I thought using XmlRootAttribute would work but I keep getting the error

```
InvalidOperationException: <DataFileSetup xmlns=''> was not expected.
```

Here is my code

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DewesoftSetup")]
public class DewesoftDevices
{
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "Devices")]
   public List<DewesoftSetup> dewesoftSiriusSetups { get; set; }

};


public class DewesoftSetup
{
   public double StartStoreTime;
   public int SampleRate;
   public int BlockSize;
   public int IBRate;
   public int AAFsr;
   public int MaxSampling;
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "Device")]
   public List<DeviceType> deviceType { get; set; }
};

public class DeviceType
{
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Type")]
   public string deviceType;

   [XmlElement(ElementName = "Slot")]
   public List<Slot> slot { get; set; }
};

public class Slot
{
   public string MeasuredValue { get; set; }
   public string Range { get; set; }
   public string LPFilter_Type { get; set; }
   public string LPFilter_Hz { get; set; }
   public string LPFilter_Order { get; set; }
   public string HPFilter_Hz { get; set; }
   public double AmplScale { get; set; }
   public double AmplOffset { get; set; }
   public string AmplShortInfo { get; set; }
   public string NamePrefix { get; set; }
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "OutputChannel")]
   public OutputChannel outputChannel;
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "AmplifierChainInfo/AmplifierInfo")]
   public AmplifierInfo ampInfo;
}

public class DewesoftCard
{
   public static string xmlFileName = @"C:\Dewesoft\SetupFile.xml";
   public double startStoreTime;
   public int sampleRate;
   public int blockSize;
   public int ibRate;
   public int aafSR;
   public int maxSampling;
   public int startZoomTime;
   public int endZoomTime;
};


public class OutputChannel
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public string Unit { get; set; }
   public int userScaleMin { get; set; }
   public int userScaleMax { get; set; }
   public int defaultComplexPresent { get; set; }
   public string Used { get; set; }
   public string Index { get; set; }
   public int DataType { get; set; }
   public double Scale { get; set; }
   public double Offset { get; set; }
   public double RangeMax { get; set; }
   public double RangeMin { get; set; }
   public int BitsLog { get; set; }
   public int SigBitCount { get; set; }
   public int BitsForMinMax { get; set; }
   public int BitCount { get; set; }
   public int ExportOrder { get; set; }
   public string MeasuredQuantity { get; set; }
   public int AmplifierScaleMin { get; set; }
   public int AmplifierScaleMax { get; set; }
};

public class AmplifierInfo
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Type { get; set; }
   public string SerialNr { get; set; }
   public string Revision { get; set; }
   public string Firmware { get; set; }
   public string CalDate { get; set; }
   public string Range { get; set; }
   public string LP_filter { get; set; }
   public string LP_filter_type { get; set; }
   public string LP_filter_order { get; set; }
   public string HP_filter { get; set; }
};
```

```
public static void readXML()
{
   XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(DewesoftCard.xmlFileName);

   reader.ReadToFollowing("DewesoftSetup");

   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DewesoftDevices));
   DewesoftDevices setup = (DewesoftDevices)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataFileSetup>
    <System Name="Local">
        <SysInfo>
            <Software>
                <VersionCreated>X3 SP5 (RELEASE-181228) (64-bit)</VersionCreated>
                <VersionModifed>X3 SP5 (RELEASE-181228) (64-bit)</VersionModifed>
                <License_Type>Professional</License_Type>
            </Software>
         </SysInfo>
         <DewesoftSetup>
            <Devices>
                <StartStoreTime>43874.6969328704</StartStoreTime>
                <SampleRate>50000</SampleRate>
                <BlockSize>1000</BlockSize>
                <IBRate>10</IBRate>
                <AAFsr>21000</AAFsr>
                <MaxSampling>200000</MaxSampling>
                <Device Type="AI">
                    <Slot Index="0">
                        <MeasuredValue>VOLTAGE</MeasuredValue>
                        <Range>10 V</Range>
                        <LPFilter_Type>BU</LPFilter_Type>
                        <LPFilter_Hz>10000</LPFilter_Hz>
                        <LPFilter_Order>2</LPFilter_Order>
                        <HPFilter_Hz>1</HPFilter_Hz>
                        <OutMathChEnabled>8;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0</OutMathChEnabled>
                        <OutputChannel>
                            <DisplayColor>#FFFF00</DisplayColor>
                            <Name>ACC-1X</Name>
                            <Description>Dome</Description>
                            <DefaultUnit>False</DefaultUnit>
                            <Unit>g</Unit>
                            <DefaultComplexPresent>1</DefaultComplexPresent>
                            <Used>True</Used>
                            <Index>AI;0</Index>
                            <DataType>4</DataType>
                            <Scale>200</Scale>
                            <RangeMax>2000</RangeMax>
                            <RangeMin>-2000</RangeMin>
                            <BitsLog>24</BitsLog>
                            <SigBitCount>19</SigBitCount>
                            <BitsForMinMax>24</BitsForMinMax>
                            <BitCount>24</BitCount>
                            <SIUnit>
                                <Label>g</Label>
                                <PhysicalQuantity>ACCELERATION</PhysicalQuantity>
                                <MetricPos>1</MetricPos>
                                <ImperialPos>1</ImperialPos>
                                <CustomPos>1</CustomPos>
                                <EditEnable>False</EditEnable>
                                <Scale>0.101972</Scale>
                            </SIUnit>
                            <MeasuredQuantity>ACCELERATION</MeasuredQuantity>
                            <OnlineInfo>
                                <IBStream Level="0"></IBStream>
                                <IBStream Level="1"></IBStream>
                                <IBStream Level="2"></IBStream>
                                <IBStream Level="3"></IBStream>
                                <IBStream Level="4"></IBStream>
                                <IBStream Level="5"></IBStream>
                            </OnlineInfo>
                            <AmplifierScaleMin>-10</AmplifierScaleMin>
                            <AmplifierScaleMax>10</AmplifierScaleMax>
                        </OutputChannel>
                        <AmplifierChainInfo>
                            <AmplifierInfo Index="0" Type="DEWEUSB_AMPLIFIER">
                                <Name>SIRIUS-HD-ACC</Name>
                                <SerialNr>D013C47522</SerialNr>
                                <Revision>1.3.0.0</Revision>
                                <Firmware>1.10</Firmware>
                                <CalDate>09.01.2020</CalDate>
                                <Measurement>Voltage</Measurement>
                                <Range>10 V</Range>
                                <LP_filter>10 kHz*  (HW: 100 kHz)</LP_filter>
                                <LP_filter_type>Butterworth*</LP_filter_type>
                                <LP_filter_order>2nd*</LP_filter_order>
                                <HP_filter>AC  1 Hz  (SW: 0.1 Hz)</HP_filter>
                            </AmplifierInfo>
                        </AmplifierChainInfo>
                   </Slot>
                </Device>
            </Devices>
        </DewesoftSetup>
  </System>
</DataFileSetup>
```

There are multiple "Device" attributes but I need the one under DewesoftSetup.

**EDIT** i have added more of the xml document. I am trying to add the device type to a list and the slot to list since there will be multiples of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            readXML();
        }
        public static void readXML()
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);

            reader.ReadToFollowing("DewesoftSetup");

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DewesoftDevices));
            DewesoftDevices setup = (DewesoftDevices)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DewesoftSetup")]
    public class DewesoftDevices
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Devices")]
        public List<Devices> devices { get; set; }

    }


    public class Devices
    {
        public string StartStoreTime;
        public int SampleRate;
        public int IBRate;
        public int AAFsr;
        public int MaxSampling;

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Device")]
        public List<DeviceType> deviceType { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeviceType
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Type")]
        public string deviceType;

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Slot")]
        public List<Slot> slot { get; set; }
    }
    public class Slot
    {
        public string Range { get; set; }
        public OutputChannel OutputChannel { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("AmplifierChainInfo")]
        [XmlArrayItem("AmplifierInfo")]
        public List<AmplifierInfo> AmplifierInfo { get; set; }
    }
    public class OutputChannel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class AmplifierInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked! Is it just because I wasnt starting from the DataFileSetup?

Comment: Yes and you needed a Device class.

Comment: I edited the code with more of the XML document. Is there a way to put the each different device in a list and each slot in a list? I have tried with the slot but it just comes back null

Comment: Make it a list From :  public Devices devices { get; set; } To :  public List<Devices> devices { get; set; }  Same with Slot.  You need XmlElement.  Without XmlElement the serialize want two levels of tags like Slots and Slot.

Comment: Can you only populate one class inside another? for example `    [XmlElement(ElementName = "OutputChannel")]
   public OutputChannel outputChannel;
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "AmplifierInfo")]
   public AmplifierInfo ampInfo { get; set; }`

AmplifierInfo and OutputChannel are on the same level

Comment: I think yes.  The parent/child of the xml and the parent/child of the classes have to concur.  So if you have multiple children in the xml files you can have multiple children in the classes.   Each class has a definition and an instance (the properties).   The class definition can be any place (not just at the root) provided you include the path like Devices.DeviceType.

Comment: I added my code. It keeps coming back null. I just need one instance of the class for each slot

Comment: I updated the classes   I made AmplifierInfo a list and added Array and ArrayItem so you do not need two classes.   You have two tags AmplifierChainInfo and AmplifierInfo so my code only needs one class for the two tags.

Comment: Ah thanks. I guess that is the only way to go. I dont need a list but not the end of the world. AmplifierChainInfo screws it up.

Thanks!

Comment: You could create two classes AmplifierChainInfo and AmplifierInfo instead of using the List.